# jsPlumb draggable element javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsplumb

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/zy1ueb5c/) will clearly allow you to understand the problem.

I want the endpoints to be binded to the elements inside each container which are draggable but only the endpoints drawn first are correct. The second time the draw function is called, the positions are incorrect and the dragging is not synced.

I have a guess that the problem lie with the CSS position but I can't find it.

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
  $(".scroll-box").draggable({
    drag: function() {
      jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
      //jsPlumb.repaint($(this)); 

    }
  });
  //            jsPlumb.draggable($(".scroll-box"));


  drawEndPoints("in-leaf", "Right");
  drawEndPoints("out-leaf", "Left");



});

function drawEndPoints(classname, endpointposition) {

  var endpointOptions = {
    isSource: true,
    isTarget: true,
    endpoint: ["Dot", {
      radius: 10
    }],
    style: {
      fillStyle: 'blue'

    },
    maxConnections: -1,
    connector: "Straight",
    connectorStyle: {
      lineWidth: 2,
      strokeStyle: 'black'
    },
    scope: "blackline",
    dropOptions: {
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        alert('drop!');
      }
    }
  };

  jsPlumb.addEndpoint($("." + classname), {
    anchor: endpointposition
  }, endpointOptions);
  //jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `jsPlumb.setContainer($("body"));`

https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/mLthybzo/

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/home

EDIT: a fiddle with your example https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/aof6mq34/

Comment: Saved the day! I'm new to jsPlumb. Are there any other important aspects I am missing? @mkaran

Comment: Glad I helped :). Hmmm I cannot recall anything that needs attention now, take a look at the [basic set up](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/home#setup) and also, it would be good to set an on window resize --> jsPlumb.repaint()  event so that jsplumb responds well to window changes. Least but not last, If you have many connectors, take advantage of `jsPlumb.setSuspendDrawing(true);`. Good luck! :)